# What is :<> in reagent hiccup?

Tags: clojure, hiccup

I don't understand the tag ":<>" in the following code
[clojure re-frame todomvc](https://github.com/day8/re-frame/blob/c12d308e6e200ba5f6b57e26121c91aa42ba5d3b/examples/todomvc/src/todomvc/views.cljs#L102)

```clojure
(defn todo-app
  []
  [:<>
   [:section#todoapp
    [task-entry]
    (when (seq @(subscribe [:todos]))
      [task-list])
    [footer-controls]]
   [:footer#info
    [:p "Double-click to edit a todo"]]])
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: The subject line should specify re-frame. This is not a feature of standard hiccup.

Comment: Reagent rather.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is creating a React Fragment:

https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: See also reagent docs: https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/CreatingReagentComponents.md

Answer (score 7):

Adding a bit more detail to the previous answer, the `fragment` gets spliced into a surrounding list instead of creating a child element. In this way, it is similar to the `unquoted-splicing` operator in Clojure `~@` compared to the regular `unquote` operator `~`.  An example:

```
(defn middle-seq       [] [    :d :e :f])
(defn middle-seq-frag  [] [:<> :d :e :f])
```

When used to create a Reagent component, we see the difference:

```
[:a :b :c (middle-seq)      :g :h :i]    ;=> [:a :b :c [:d :e :f] :g :h :i]
[:a :b :c (middle-seq-frag) :g :h :i]    ;=> [:a :b :c  :d :e :f  :g :h :i]
```

Otherwise, you would have to restructure the input and use `concat`:

```
(vec
  (concat
    [:a :b :c]
    (middle-seq) 
    [:g :h :i] ))          ;=> [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i]
```